# Showing that $(X^*)^{**}=(X^{**})^{*}$, where $X$ is a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $X^*$ denote the dual space . Would you help me, How to show that $(X^*)^{**}=(X^{**})^*$?

Comment: Would downvoter explain why all the answers were downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just playing with symbols. By definition
$$
Y^*=\mathcal{B}(Y,\mathbb{C})
$$
for any normed space $Y$. So
$$
X^{**}=(X^*)^*=\mathcal{B}(X^*,\mathbb{C})=\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{B}(X,\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{C})
$$
$$
(X^{**})^*=\mathcal{B}(X^{**},\mathbb{C})=\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{B}(X,\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{C})
$$
and on the other hand
$$
(X^*)^{**}=\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{B}(X^*,\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{C})=\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{B}(X,\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{C})
$$
Hence 
$$
(X^{**})^*=(X^*)^{**}
$$

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of notation:

$$X^{**}:=(X^{*})^{*}$$

for all normed vector spaces X, so

$$(X^*)^{**}=((X^*)^*)^*=(X^{**})^*.$$

Comment: No. I find the question from exercise of conway book

Comment: @Sean Gomes Please, explain your argument.

Comment: The double dual of a normed vector space $X$ is the vector space that arises from taking the dual of the dual of $X$. If we explicitly write this by using brackets, both the left hand side and the right hand side reduce to the middle...the space that arises from taking the dual of X three times recursively.

Comment: What is the number of the exercise?

Comment: @GEdgar: exercise no 2 page 90